# Convert object reference to STL iterator

Tags: c++, stl, reference, iterator

I am using std::multimap<> and I pass pointer to an element (T*) to a component written in C.

When the component wants to delete the object it calls back to C++ supplying the pointer, however, I am not sure whether there is a way to convert T* into std::multimap<>::iterator so that I can call erase().

Any ideas?

Comment: "`std::multimap<>`" No. `std::multimap<>` isn't a type. What is the type of your container? What is `T`? The key info is missing.

Answer (score 3):

If you can determine the key from the item, you can use equal_range to get all the possible matches, then call find on that range.

If there isn't a way to get from an item to it's key (rare but possible), then one could enumerate through the whole multimap (from begin() to end()) and erase the one that matches. Hopefully this would be a rare operation, as it is O(N).

Comment: First one is O(log n), second is O(n), however, iterator is technically a pointer, so there should be an O(1) way. If there's not it will be the first performance shortcoming of STL I've encountered during the years I'm using it :)

Comment: `std::multimap` maps keys to values.  There's nothing in the standard that mandates an O(1) way to go from a value to its key.  An iterator looks and behaves a lot like a pointer, but nothing says it actually has to be one.

Comment: coriousguy: iterator to *multimap* is technically a pointer. The standard guarantees that access to the element via iterator is O(1) and that the iterator stays valid even though you modify/delete other elements in the map. AFAICS there's no other way to implement that two requirements than make the iterator either a pointer or a similar kind of reference easily convertible to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse pointers and iterators. Sometimes (e.g. arrays) a pointer can function as iterator. But it doesn't necessarily.

Iterators in C++ will usually overload the `*` operator aka "dereference operator". This makes them look like C pointers even more, when they technically may or may not be the same.

Passing iterators is in general fragile, and I'd avoid this. In particular, a concurrent modification of the multimap in your case may render the iterator invalid.

Comment: Yes, it will. Still, is there a way to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a multimap is a set of key-value pairs.  It sounds like your `T*` is a *value* and you need an efficient way to get its *key* so you can remove it.  Have you considered [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)?  That library allows efficient mappings both ways.  Then it should be simple to take the `T*` from the calling code, lookup the key, and erase it.

Comment: I want deletion in O(1) not O(log n) that bi-directional map would provide. Also, introducing a Boost dependency into a project just to solve this minor problem is a bit of overkill. I've ended up storing a iterator pointing to the element in the element itself. It's kind of stupid, but it seems this kind of thing cannot be done using STL in a sane way.